# Serviceworker.js code being shown on page (only in Google) each time i open root site directory and being replaced with index.html after ctrl+f5

Tags: django, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I guess, it is something about django-pwa. This problem appears only in google chrome (in local mode it even works fine on 127.0.0.1:8000 but doesnt work on localhost:8000).

My project structure:

```
D:.
├───api
│   └───migrations
├───core
│   └───__pycache__
├───games
│   └───migrations
├───main
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───images
│   └───js
├───staticfiles
└───templates
```

it appears, that chrome browser requests the empty path for pwa.urls firstly, but other browsers requesting main urls. i dont really how to make chrome request my urls from main app on first place.

**this is my urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
import debug_toolbar

schema_url_patterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include('api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('main.urls')),
    path('openapi', get_schema_view(
        title="Gamers Gazette",
        description="API!",
        version="1.0.0",
        patterns=schema_url_patterns,
        ), name='openapi-schema'),

    path('swagger-ui/', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='swagger-ui.html',
        extra_context={'schema_url':'openapi-schema'}
    ), name='swagger-ui'),

    path('redoc/', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='redoc.html',
        extra_context={'schema_url':'openapi-schema'}
    ), name='redoc'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('games/', include('games.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('api.urls')),
    path("", include("pwa.urls")),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

**this is my serviceworker.js:**

```
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';
 
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    this.skipWaiting();
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
    )
});

// Clear cache on activate
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName.startsWith("django-pwa-")))
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName !== staticCacheName))
                    .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
            );
        })
    );
});

// Serve from Cache
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                return caches.match('offline');
            })
    )
});
```

**the settings.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PWA_SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js', 'serviceworker.js')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fl61624yl*s1hbc9lt@9ipbmyytdrurqo@dc%$3pdz9g8haof3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
SESSIONS_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #apps
    'main',
    'api',
    'games',
    #django staff
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #drf staff
    'rest_framework',
    #debugging
    "debug_toolbar",
    #third_party
    "pwa"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    #django staff
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    'debug_toolbar_force.middleware.ForceDebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'main_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432' 
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

if DEBUG:
    import socket  # only if you haven't already imported this
    hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    INTERNAL_IPS = [ip[:-1] + '1' for ip in ips] + ['127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.2']

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache:11211',
    }
}

#PWA STAFF
PWA_APP_NAME = 'test app'
PWA_APP_DESCRIPTION = "test app PWA"
PWA_APP_THEME_COLOR = '#000000'
PWA_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#ffffff'
PWA_APP_DISPLAY = 'standalone'
PWA_APP_SCOPE = '/'
PWA_APP_ORIENTATION = 'any'
PWA_APP_START_URL = '/'
PWA_APP_STATUS_BAR_COLOR = 'default'
PWA_APP_ICONS = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/icon.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_ICONS_APPLE = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/icon.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_SPLASH_SCREEN = [
    {
        'src': 'static/images/icon.png',
        'media': '(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)'
    }
]
PWA_APP_DIR = 'ltr'
PWA_APP_LANG = 'ru-RU'

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

ask eweryting You need

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for iterrupting, the problew was in Google. It cached a wrong version of script, after cleaning cache ewerything was fine.